# Setting a data attribute of an element based on its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, getelementbyid

I am trying to set the `data-whatever` attribute of this element:

```
<a
    class='btn-lg btn-success bg-primary'
    id='vsIDButton'
    data-toggle='modal'
    href='#messageModal'
    role='button'
    data-whatever=''>New Message</a>
```

Right now I managed to do it by replacing the whole element, but there should be a better way.

I have tried this and a few variations around this, using `innerHTML`:

```
const vSourceID="contact:7573981724739861"; 

document.getElementById("vsIDButton.attr('data-whatever')").innerHTML = vSourceID;
```

I have also tried this jQuery function I found in StackOverflow:

I have tried both this:

```
SetButton(vSourceID); 

function SetButton() {
    $('#vsIDButton > data-whatever').html();
}
```

And this:

```
SetButton(vSourceID);

function SetButton(x) {
    $('#vsIDButton > data-whatever').html(x);
}
```

Comment: The id of the element is `vsIDButton` so that would be the string you pass to `.getElementById()`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn there should be no need to qualify the id selector, since the id has to be unique anyway.

Comment: You want to set `data-whatever=''` OR want to replace the text `New Message` with this?

Comment: Rohit - I want to set data-whatever=''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like.

```
    let vSourceID="contact:7573981724739861"; 
    document.getElementById("vsIDButton").setAttribute('data-whatever', vSourceID);
```

Make sure you are using unique `id` as `vsIDButton`

OR

```
    SetButton(vSourceID);
    function SetButton(x) {
       $('#vsIDButton').attr('data-whatever',x);
    }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to set the `data-whatever` attribute to some new value, not the content of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Yes I asked it just now

Comment: Thanks, guys - so quick! I went for a walk and came back... - Rohit I tried both your solutions and both worked exactly, thank you. I can now get rid of a lot of document writes!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `document.getElementById`, you should only pass it the `id` attribute, which in your case is `vsIDButton`.

Then, to set a data attribute you can use [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) or [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), depending on what browsers you need to support:

```js
const vSourceID = 'contact:7573981724739861'; 

// Using setAttribute:
document.getElementById('vsIDButton').setAttribute('data-whatever', vSourceID);

// Using dataset (you only need one or another):
document.getElementById('vsIDButton').dataset.whatever = vSourceID;
```

```css
#vsIDButton::before {
  /*
    This will display the value of the data-whatever attribute
    in a ::before pseudo-element so that we can easily see that
    the JS code is working.
  */
  content: attr(data-whatever);
}
```

```html
<div id="vsIDButton"></div>
```

Note that when using `dataset`, you don't need to add the `data-` prefix, so you just do:

```
document.getElementById('vsIDButton').dataset.whatever = vSourceID;
```

These have nothing to do with [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which is used to get or set the HTML or XML markup contained within an element, not its attributes.